# Linq -search in two columns

Tags: c#

I have firstname and surname in the database in user table

I have stored **Billy Bob** in Firstname fields and **Charles** in Surname Field.

I am trying to search for the user by **Bob Charles**

I am using the following query to get the results but I do not get any results. I believe Contains keyword should bring me any matching words in the query.

Here name I am passing as **Bob Charles**

```
 var query = from user in UserEntity
                        where user.FirstName.Contains(name) || user.Surname.Contains(name)
                        select user;
```

I should get that one row in my query.

What is being missed here please?

Comment: You are passing in name = "Bob Charles" but neither the FirstName nor the LastName contains "Bob Charles"

Answer (score 2):

Both columns do not contain `"Bob Charles"`, you want to look for `Bob` in `FirstName` and `Charles` in `Surname` unless I am mistaken.

```
string bothNames = name.Split(); // Bob + Charles
string firstName = bothNames.First();
string lastname = bothNames.Last();
var query = from user in UserEntity
            where user.FirstName.Contains(firstName) || user.Surname.Contains(lastname)
            select user;
```

Comment: You cannot reliably use the first and last word of a name as the first and last name.  Between titles, suffixes, multi-word names, the possible presence of middle names, etc. that is simply not a reliable parsing.  Searching on `Billy Bob` will look for users with a last name containing `Bob`, which would be wrong.

Comment: @Servy: we only have one sample `"Bob Charles"`, i don't know the source of it, maybe OP has already created it from two strings or TextBoxes. The core of my answer is that he needs to search for both separately.

Comment: Yes, but the core of your answer requires solving an insolvable problem.  That makes it a poor answer.  You *don't* solve that problem.  You provide a solution that will work in some cases, and not another.  You can't expect the OP to solve that sub-problem effectively on his own, because unless it's an option for him to have separate UI fields for first and last name, there's no way of separating the two concepts out once they're stuck together.

Answer (score 2):

Your LINQ is fine, but you are searching for `Bob Charles` in `Billy Bob` and `Charles` respectively, which is why you're not receiving any results.

Here's what I suggest:

```
var query = user.Where(u => (u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName).Contains(name));
```

Answer (score 1):

`Billy Bob` does NOT contain `Bob Charles` and neither does `Charles`.  You need to parse the passed `Bob Charles` into `Bob` and `Charles` and search for each one separately.

Answer (score 1):

you should really have the first name and the last name stored in 2 different variables:

`Bob` and `Charles`

`Charles` does not contain `Bob Charles`, and neither does `Billy Bob`

Answer (score 1):

> I believe Contains keyword should bring me any matching words in the query

Wrong - it will return results where *the entire string* is contained in either `FirstName` or `SurName`.  Since neither `Billy Bob` nor `Charles` *contains* `Bob Charles` it will not be returned as a result.

Some options:

- Split the query into words and see if *any* of those words are in your name fields
- Concatenate the two name fields (separated by a space) and see if that contains your query

The method you choose depends on how strict you want your search to be.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say we search for **"Bob Charles"** and we have:

```
string name = "Bob Charles";
var namesToSearch = name.Split(' ').ToList();

var UserEntities = new List<UserEntity>();
    UserEntities.Add(new UserEntity { FirstName = "Bily Bob", Surname = "Charles" }); // user1
    UserEntities.Add(new UserEntity { FirstName = "Bob", Surname = "Adam" }); // user2
    UserEntities.Add(new UserEntity { FirstName = "Anna", Surname = "Brown" }); // user3
    UserEntities.Add(new UserEntity { FirstName = "Charles", Surname = "Bob" }); // user4
```

If you want **user1**, **user2** and **user4** in the result (meaning: all the users that have either "Bob" or "Charles" in their first name or surname):

```
var query = UserEntities.Where(a => (a.FirstName + " " + a.Surname).Split(' ').Any(b => namesToSearch.Contains(b)));
```

If you want only **user1** and **user4** in the result (meaning: the users that have both "Bob" and "Charles" in their first name or surname):

```
var query = UserEntities.Where(a => namesToSearch.All(b=> (a.FirstName + " " + a.Surname).Split(' ').Contains(b)));
```

If you want a **user1** in the result(meaning: the users that have "Bob" in their first name and "Charles" in their surname):

```
var query = UserEntities.Where(a => a.FirstName.Split(' ').Contains(namesToSearch[0]) && a.Surname.Split(' ').Contains(namesToSearch[1]));
```